# ToggleButton change color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have two `ToggleButton` in my activity. I want to click on the first button and have its color change to white. If I click on the second button, the color of first button should change to black and the color of second button change to white.

I want to know which button is selected. How can I do this with `ToggleButton`, or with something else?

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/tg_btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46px"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/tg_btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46px"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Please help me, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

use a Style for your Toggle Button

```
<style name="ToggleButton.YourTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Apply that to your button and it should work. Have not tested it recently.

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/tg_btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46px"
    android:theme="@style/ToggleButton.YourTheme"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have two ToggleButtons in an activity which, when ToggleButton1 is clicked, ONLY that button changes color and the other one does not, but then when the ToggleButton2 is switched on: the ToggleButton1 turns "off" and ToggleButton2 turns "on", I created two global variables: One boolean for the first toggle, and a boolean for the second toggle.

```
package com.example.micha_000.togglecolors;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Boolean toggleOneOn = false;
    Boolean toggleTwoOn = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void ToggleOne(View view){
        //If the Toggle Button is off
        if(!toggleOneOn){
            //This view element references the ToggleButton1
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            toggleOneOn = true;
        }
        //If it is is clicked while on
        else{
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            toggleOneOn = false;
        }

    }

    public void ToggleTwo(View view){
        //If the Toggle Button is clicked while off
        if(!toggleTwoOn){
            //This view element references the ToggleButton2
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            //This ToggleButton element references the ToggleButton1
            ToggleButton toggle1 = findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton1);
            toggle1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            toggleOneOn = false;
            toggleTwoOn = true;
        }
        //If it is is clicked while on
        else{
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            toggleTwoOn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I then used the "onClick" property in xml to reference the ToggleOne and ToggleTwo methods I created in my java class (Those methods must be public, void, and have a View as a parameter as they do in my code). I then have conditionals checking those global booleans, and then using "setBackgroundColor" to change the color of the toggle appropriately.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ToggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="ToggleOne"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ToggleButton2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="ToggleTwo"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ToggleButton1"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

If you wanted to switch the other toggle button when one is pressed, you just need to adjust what happens inside the if/else statements inside the toggleButton methods

---